# SQL code assist in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.1 I connected Data Source to Oracle database.
When I open an *.sql file and type

```
 SELECT * FROM
```

I see in code completion list of available tables. Also table columns of selected table are available in WHERE part of statement
But when I type

```
INSERT INTO
```

No table is available in code completion.
The same for SQL console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80264). It's already fixed in [IDEA 12 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP) and will be also fixed in IDEA 11.1.4 (not released at the moment of writing this answer).